# How to debug Next.js dev server hanging and preventing any further requests? Is there a way to get more data?

Tags: next.js

My `Next.js` dev server starts hanging and I'm not sure how to debug it or get more verbose logging out of it.

I've been blindly logging network requests, changing node versions, Next.js versions, dropping timers in my next.js functions, enabling node debug mode, trying to uncover a common thread, but I'm not getting anywhere.

How do I debug this properly? Is there a way to detect open connections, any kind of stats that would be useful here with Next.js or generally speaking?

I have tried CPU profiles, memory snapshots, but am not able to interpret anything useful.

All requests to the dev server start hanging (pending) in network state. The only solution is to kill the process and restart it.

Higher level recommendations are welcome too.

The fact that I do not know how to profile the dev server itself, is currently a huge risk to any Next.js project.

Comment: Technically, Webpack HMR request should never "complete". It maintains the connection between your dev server and the browser for hot reloading. What exactly happens in your case when the server is hung? And have your tried using some other browser or a clean/guest profile on Chrome, or disabling extensions? Also, what does _"I know we're limited to 6 connections per domain"_ mean?

Comment: In the screenshot of waterfall that you have attached, HMR request is fine. The TTFB of `[personSlug].js` is high. Also, its not resolving. ~30s for 1.6MB is more than expected (for local server or are you running your dev server on some internal IP?). Also, can you verify that you have not throttled the network?

Comment: @brc-dd Not throttled. I meant the http connection limit per domain which is 6-8 ish. Fresh browser with no extensions (good call!), is a hanging dev server issue it seems.

Comment: I had this happen on a project and couldn't fix or find the issue.  I created a fresh Next.js install and copied my custom code without modification, and it worked as expected.   You could try a fresh install; if it works, move your code over.